# Using Imports with .Net, React.Js, and Url.Content

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, reactjs, razor-pages

I am using a .Net MVC framework, and trying to render a jsx (React) file that has imports. I am including this file in the razor page (cshtml) through the standard Url.Content injection as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/queue/QueueIndex.js")"></script>
<script>
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(QueueIndex), document.getElementById("queue-index"));

    jQuery(window).on("load scroll", function () {
        'use strict'; // Start of use strict
        // Loader
        $("#dvLoading").fadeOut("fast");
    });
</script>
```

If I do not have an import at the top of my React file (QueueIndex.jsx) the page loads just fine. However, I would like to import the react-table package, but if include any imports in my QueueIndex.jsx file, the page breaks.

The error I'm getting is require is not defined.

I think the solution is somewhere in the use of webpack, here is my config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    nhqueue: './wwwroot/js/queue/QueueIndex.jsx'
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/wwwroot/js/',
    publicPath: '/wwwroot/js/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
module: {
    preLoaders: [
    ],
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        },
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['babel', 'ts'] },
        { test: /\.json$ /, loader: "json-loader" },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel",
            query:
            {
                presets: ['react']
            }
        }
    ],
    externals: {
        "moment": "moment",
    },
},
devtool: 'source-map',
target: 'web',
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./wwwroot/js/*.js'], {
        root: __dirname,
        verbose: true,
        dry: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
],
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js', '.tsx', '.ts']
},
node: {
    fs: "empty",
    child_process: "empty"
}
}
```

Unfortunately, I have had no luck there. Please let me know if you have any ideas of how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Also, Here is the Babel configuration:

```
{"presets" : ["es2015", "react"]}
```

Comment: Can you add more details? Do you get this error on the Webpack build? Runtime? How babel is configured?

Comment: Hi, so I get there error on runtime (like in the console). I have added my babelrc file to the question, if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: I am just quessing .. you are including queueIndex.js, but such file should not exist (probably babel temp file). Based on your webpack config the js file should be /js/nhqueue.bundle.js